# Angular Web App Works Locally, But Not In Azure

Tags: angular, azure, routes

I am trying to make the jump from AngularJS to Angular 2 and onwards. I got this:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-2-routing-with-multiple-components-using-visual-studio-ide/

working locally with not much trouble, but when I publish it to Azure here:

http://potrangulartest14-10-2020.azurewebsites.net/

it dosn't work. I've read everything I can, with multiple sources over the web saying that I have to  set my WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION application setting value to 10.6.0, or to add this to my web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

but nothing is working. Can someone explain how I get this Angular example to work in Azure like it does locally please? It appears that the Angular routing elements are simply not being built in Azure, despite being present and complete so as to work locally. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you try with just a simple web.config: Such as:  <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"  />
    </system.webServer>

Comment: I assume you have built your spa for production and have the dist folder present on your app service.

Comment: I can't get that web.config to work, as it complains about the path being empty. I've tried this on both debug and release, and it makes no difference.

Comment: Looking at your live site, there are references to scripts inside node_modules folder. Did you build for production, rather than development? The scripts should be bundled up and referenced directly instead from node modules folder as presumably this doesn't exist in your app service.

Comment: I tried building it under both Debug mode and Release mode in Visual Studio before publishing it to Azure. I don't know anything more than that. The end result seems to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, have got this working now. There were multiple references to .js files that were located within the node_modules folder, as said by Allan above (thank you Allan).

This worked locally, but as they weren't included in my project, they didn't work when published to the cloud. Including these files in the project solved the issue.

If anyone has any advice about whether this is usual to simply include these files in the project, or whether there is a better way of packaging this up, then I'd love to hear it. I don't want to end up including the whole node_modules folder, but where to draw the line?

Thanks for any information I can learn from here, and thanks to Allan once again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Unless you're trying to do server-side rendering, you should _not_ need `node_modules` in production. The output of your build should be static HTML, JS, CSS bundles.